# Replace item in vector by id

Tags: clojure

```
(defonce channels (atom []))

(defn register-channel! [id tag channel]
  (swap! channels conj [id tag channel]))

(register-channel! "456" :player {})

@channels ;; => [["456" :player {}]]
```

The id and tag are the indexes for the data, the id is unique, the tag is not. 
I can `conj` new items on to channels. But calling `register-channel!` with an existing id will not `conj` a new item instead the third element, channel, of the existing item should be changed.

Here is what I have, which works:

```
(defn register-channel! [id tag channel]
  (let [without-id (remove #(= id (first %)) @channels)
        with-id (conj without-id [id tag channel])]
    (reset! channels with-id)))
```

I'm pretty sure there is a more elegant way :)

Note that I am using a collection of vector because I'll only ever have 3 elements, I could use a map if there is no significant performance penalty. However I will need to write functions to find a channel by id or channels by tag afterwards, e.g.

```
(defn one-by-id [id] (first (filter #(= id (first %)) @channels)))
(defn many-by-tag [tag] (filter #(= tag (second %)) @channels))
```

Comment: If you don't _require_ a vector, you could use a map in your atom instead and do `(swap! channels assoc id channel)` in your simpler `register-channel!` implementation.

Comment: I guess I over simplified the question a little, it doesn't have to be a vector, but it does have another identifier other than `id` called `tag` which is non-unique. So it it would either be a 3 element vector or a map.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need channels to be a vector of pairs, you can add or replace new channels like this:

```
> (vec (assoc (into {} [[:a 1]]) :a 2))
[[:a 2]]

> (vec (assoc (into {} [[:a 1]]) :b 2))
[[:a 1] [:b 2]]
```

But that begs the question of whether you'd rather have channels itself be a map.

Define the atom as an empty map and job done!

```
(defonce channels (atom {}))

(defn register-channel! [id channel]
  (swap! channels conj [id channel]))

> (register-channel! "456" {:a 1})
{"456" {:a 1}}
> (register-channel! "457" {:a 1})
{"456" {:a 1}, "457" {:a 1}}
> (register-channel! "457" {:a 2})
{"456" {:a 1}, "457" {:a 2}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in the case of the first example, the vector will have more than two elements. I perhaps over simplified the question, which I will now adjust. I could use a map, if it performs well compared to an vector, but I need to `filter` the vector of map based on either the id or another key. I will update the question to reflect this.